# How do I properly close my BinaryReader class so I can open the same file again?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, io

Using VC++ 2010, .NET 3.5

My app is crashing on the 2nd iteration of this do..while loop on this line

```
System::IO::BinaryReader^ binReader = ...
```

.

```
System::String^ fileName = GetFileName();
bool continue = true;
do {
    System::IO::BinaryReader^ binReader = gcnew System::IO::BinaryReader(System::IO::File::Open(fileName, System::IO::FileMode::Open));
    //
    // read file,
    // do things,
    //
    binReader.close();
    delete binReader;
} while (continue);
```

It compiles fine, but when run, I get the "..stopped working" dialog (on the 2nd iteration, I checked by putting a ::MessageBox() at the beginning of the loop)

How do I properly close my BinaryReader class so I can open the same file again?

Comment: It's likely the "read file, do things" code is the problem. Does it still crash if you comment it out?

Comment: Wierd, I thought the `delete` (forget the close) would be sufficient. If you remove the `gcnew` and the `delete`, does it follow stack semantics and just work? (This is actually better from an exception safe point of view anyway). One quick point, that might not even be your problem, find out what the exception is using a debugger (not message boxes).